# BluetoothGattCallback never happening? Status = 0?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

**UPDATE:** Question is irrelevant.  Careful debugging showed that it was reaching the connection state change.  I just need to learn more of the tools built into android-studio.  Reading the GATT documentation on the android website shows that Status = 0 indicates a successful connection, not some null state that I believed.

For others concerned about their GATT status the documentation is found here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html

**ORIGINAL**:
I am trying to connect to a Bluetooth LE device using Android studio and am able to find it and attempt to connect to it.  The device stops blinking, indicating that it is still connected, however I cannot get the code to ever reach my BluetoothGattCallback.  The log also reads

```
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=F4:B8:5E:A6:CE:D0 Status=0
06-06 16:35:09.682 17511-19374/com.somesite.dl503.vacuumgauge D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=F4:B8:5E:A6:CE:D0 interval=39 status=0
06-06 16:35:13.112 17511-17522/com.somesite.dl503.vacuumgauge D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=F4:B8:5E:A6:CE:D0 interval=15 status=0
```

Has anyone else ever encountered Status = 0 or it never entering the Gatt callback?

Connected by the code:

```
mConnectedGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_AUTO);
```

My Gatt callback onConncectionStateChange which should be called first, right?

```
@Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                gatt.discoverServices();
            } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {

            } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                gatt.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @kevin I am facing same issue did you get any solution ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you guys find anything?